# constraintsWithVisualFormat set same Y position for all the views

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I am just playing with `constraintsWithVisualFormat` but not able to figure out how to do.

I have two Views placed together with 10 pix margin in horizontal. and Y position will be the same for the both of the views.

I have tried the following things.

```
 [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[view1(==100)]-10-[view2(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[view1(==100)]-[view2(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
```

> Horizontal Constraint : 10 pix left margin from superview - 100 width
>   of view1- 10 pix margin - 100 width of view2
>
> Vertical Constraint : 10 pix top from superview - 100 height of view1-
>   100 height of view2

**Problem**
   The second view Y position start after the view1 i want the same Y position for the both of the view.

Please if possible explain the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark '-' is margin 8px in VisualFormatLanguage.

Try this.

```
`[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[view1(==100)]-10-[view2(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[view1(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[view2(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];`
```

Comment: Yes got it.. there is one extra bracket in V:|-10-[view1(==100)]] so change it

Comment: Mark '-' is not 8px, it is some default value that depends on the class of view and other properties. Note that it is no way to create '-' manually with [NSLyaoutConstraint initWith...], only through VFL.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal layout with *all bottom alignment*:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[view1(==100)]-10-[view2(==100)]"
                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:views]
```

Vertical layout untouched:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[view1]"
                                        options:0
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:views]
```

Please also note that two approaches -- constrain each view at top of superview vs. align all views around common top/bottom/baseline/centery differ in obvious way. And that other answer cannot address the case of center-alignment, btw.

UPD: Here is a complete working example of using alignment options in layout:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSTextField *view1 = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    NSTextField *view2 = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

    NSView *contentView = [self.window contentView];
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view1, view2);

    [view1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [view2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [contentView addSubview:view1];
    [contentView addSubview:view2];

    [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[view1(==100)]-[view2(==100)]"
                                                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views]];
    [contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[view1]"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views]];
}
```

[image: Results]

Comment: No there is no constraint for the Y position of the view2

Comment: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom is exactly for that. Added some description.

Comment: @SidShah I did not test it before, but it works without changes. Two text edits one after other [   ] [   ]. What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I m not able to see anything on the view'

Comment: It is probably because your views are custom and do not have fixed vertical size (as text fields). Then you should not omit height in @"V:|-[view1]", i.e. fix it too @"V:|-[view1(==100)]". Post your efforts here if in doubt. Or just stick with accepted answer -- it is up to you.

Comment: Ok got it its not taking the height.. I have added two constraints V:|-[view1(==100)] and V:|-[view2(==100)]